# Cascade Operation is missing

Tags: jooq

In hibernate we have lot of cascading options between parent and child entities

Is there is any framework which builds on top of JOOQ provides the flexibility

How to adopt cascade in a simpler way in JooQ

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jOOQ way to do this would be the SQL way. In SQL (much like in object orientation) you generally distinguish between aggregation (no cascading) and composition (cascading).

**Composition**

When you design your database schema and create a composition like the `actor` - `film_actor` - `film` relationships, you would define the `film_actor` table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE film_actor (
  actor_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES actor ON DELETE CASCADE,
  film_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES film ON DELETE CASCADE,

  PRIMARY KEY (actor_id, film_id)
);
```

It is a composition because a `film_actor` child record cannot exist without its parents. And you wouldn't worry about cascading in the client, because this information belongs in your database schema.

**Aggregation**

With aggregations, the child record can exist without its parent. An example for this are `store` and `staff`, if you want to model this as a 1:N relationship:

```sql
CREATE TABLE store (
  store_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ...

  PRIMARY KEY (store_id)
);

CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  store_id BIGINT     NULL REFERENCES store ON DELETE SET NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);
```

There are different philosophies to modelling aggregations. The reasonable default is probably to not specify any `ON DELETE` clause (defaulting to `ON DELETE NO ACTION` in most dialects), but if available `ON DELETE SET NULL` can also be a useful cascading action, so you don't have to worry about this all the time.

**What jOOQ can do**

A `DELETE .. CASCADE` synthetic SQL statement is on the roadmap in jOOQ, but it will not be a silver bullet, because it is unwise to think that all deletions are the same (see above distinction): https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7367

Apart from that, it is usually a good thing to not blindly cascade all sorts of operations but think about them explicitly, especially when a lot of aggregations are involved. Deletions are hardly as simple as shown above, neither with jOOQ, nor with native SQL, nor with Hibernate.

Imagine that only for 2-3 tables, you want to implement deletions logically only. So a cascading delete wouldn't work in simple ways (unless your database product supports SQL:2011 `SYSTEM_TIME` versioned tables, such as e.g. Db2, MariaDB, Oracle, SQL Server).

If you know what tables are involved, you could of course implement `RecordListener` or `VisitListener` implementations that would be triggered to delete child records automatically. Or you could resort to using triggers for more complex cases. Or you create a set of base `DAO` or `Repository` or whatever you want to call them implementations, which navigate the database meta model that is generated by jOOQ to make decisions about what to delete automatically.